# What component (IC) to use for collecting A and !A signals into a single TTL signal?

Tags: integrated-circuit, encoder, differential, quadrature

I am building a circuit board to listen to quadrature encoder signals from a motor controller and send these signals on to an FPGA that will be used to count the pulses and direction. The signals coming out of my motor controller are:

- Phase A: A and !A
- Phase B: B and !B
- Phase C: C and !C (origin indicator)

In other words, each phase sends out two signals that are the opposite of one another at all times. I have used Quad EIA-422/423 (MC3486) line receivers to convert differential voltage signals into TTL signals, but is this the correct component for converting each phase from two signals to a single TTL signal? If not, is there a similar IC that will do the trick?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** It looks like I was treating these signals correctly. I was a little confused on the definition of "differential voltage" as it applies to the line receivers I am using (MC3486). Basically when A is `high` and !A is `low`, my line receiver outputs a `high` on the TTL channel. When A is `low` and !A is `high`, it outputs a `low` on the TTL channel. This is what I wanted it to do; I was concerned that I had misinterpreted the meaning of differential voltage.

Comment: It depends on the voltage levels on your signals. Are they compatible with RS-422? If not, you might use a quad comparator with suitable voltage dividers on the inputs, along with some positive feedback for hysteresis.

Comment: Signals that are opposite are basically redundant; if you have A, you can regenerate !A.   There are IC's that take digital quadrature signals and decode them: they are used with digital potentiometers and encoder strips. These IC's put out simplified signals like pulses to count up and down (and some even have registers that do the counting and can be read out, I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a point-to-point system you are trying to "sniff" the data from and because of this you'd be well-advised to offer a high-impedance connection which can suffer a reasonable bit of common-mode voltage on the two lines relative to your "sniffer".

I don't know what data rate it's using but it'd be hard-pressed to task a [MAX999](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX961-MAX999.pdf) comparator.

I'd use 10k resistors from each line to the MAX999 inputs and I'd have 2 series 470R resistors across the MAX999 inputs to: -

1. Attenuate the signal
2. Act as a mid rail connection from your local sniffer power

The MAX999 will work down to very low input levels and attenuating most data transmission levels by ten is not going to be a big issue. The MAX999 also has a littel bit of inbuilt hysteresis too and works at 5V or 3V3 with a push-pull output that can directly feed micros and PLDs etc..

[image]

Comment: You are correct that I was trying to sniff the data in a point-to-point system, but my question was more about whether using a line receiver is the right way to read these differential voltage signals. I was a little confused about the definition of "differential voltage" for line receivers, but I think I got it now.

Comment: @Engineero No, I wouldn't use a line receiver because of unknown common-mode voltages that may exist and that they may want to sniff a little more current and potentially upset the comms.

Comment: OK, that is not something I am familiar with, but I will look in to it more. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

> A dedicated voltage comparator chip such as [LM339](http://www.ti.com/product/lm339) is designed to interface with a digital logic interface (to a TTL or a CMOS).

[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fffO7m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: ummm... there's something missing around the output pin of the LM339...

Comment: Right, OC comparator.

Comment: Great, thank you. I think that is exactly what my MC3486 is doing. It looks like I was treating these signals correctly, which was my concern originally.